# Publishing the subitems of related items

Tags: publishing

I've got a navigation folder outside of the home node that contains a folder for each navigation bar (IE header and footer for simplicity). Under that navigation bar folder are the items that should appear on the menu. Then the "header" or "footer" item has a drop link to hook the appropriate menu to the appropriate spot.

When publishing from the homepage and using "publish related" any changes made to the individual navigation items aren't being pushed, because they're not the directly related item, but a subitem of the related item. I found one blog that suggested this was possible - https://abarhoum.com/2016/08/29/deep-publishing-of-related-items-with-sitecroe-experience-editor/. But I tried implementing that and the menu item didn't push out.

Has anyone accomplished something similar to this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore uses a concept of [pipelines for publishing](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/How-does-publishing-work#how-does-publishing-work). When an item is published, there is a `AddItemReferences` processor that is responsible for locating related items.

It launches `getItemReferences` pipeline in Sitecore 10.1.
So all you might need to do is to add a processor into that pipeline to add the items you think are to be published/processed together.